# Search bar and dropdown moved and I can't get them back into place. Something is wrong with CSS. I checked everything

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
<-- somewhere in the CSS, lies the error that is being made regarding my Nav bar. It's possible it could be in the HTML or both. For whatever the reason, the Calendars, Contact and Search bar got moved out of place. I have checked everywhere in this code and cannot find the error. Perhaps someone more experienced than I am can help me locate the issue inside of the CSS and or HTML -->

/*nav bar*/
.navbar input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
.navbar .search-container button:hover {
    background: #ccc;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar .search-container {
      float: none;
    }
    .navbar a, .navbar input[type=text], .navbar .search-container button {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 14px;
    }
    .navbar input[type=text] {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;  
    }
  }

.navbar {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }

  .navbaritems {
      float: left;
      display: inline;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  h1 {
      text-align: center;
  }

  /*a link style*/

  a:link {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  a:visited {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  a:active {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  /* Calendar Dropdown Menu */
  li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<!-- this section the HTML code for the website. The dropdown, searchbar and contact portions of the code I believe are causing issue -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>News</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>News</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul class=navbar>
                <li class="navbaritems"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navbaritems"><a href="#Page2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li class="navbaritems"><a href="#Page3">Page 3</a></li>
                <li class="navbaritems"><a href="#Page4">Page 4</a></li>
                
                <div class="navbaritems" class="dropdown">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#DropdownPage1">Dropdown Page 1</a>
                        <a href="#DropdownPage2">Dropdown Page 2</a>
                        <a href="#DropdownPage3">Dropdown Page 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class=navbaritems><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <input type="text" class=searchbar placeholder="Search.." name="Search" name="searchbar">
                <!-- Fix the button for the search bar https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_searchbar3 <button type="submit" class=search-container><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>-->
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!--Article Feed Goes Here-->
        <!--Need to add Advertising mechanism to this section of the website-->
    </main>
    <footer>
        <!--Put "Terms of Service" and "Privacy Policy" here-->
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if that solves your problem, but there is an unclosed <div> =>   <div class="navbaritems" class="dropdown">

Comment: `Something is wrong with CSS. I checked everything` is not helpful. You need to be way more specific. Add a detailed description. `Search bar and dropdown moved and I can't get them back into place. ` also not very detailed. Moved to where? what outcome was expected? Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: If you mean that they should be aligned vertically, you can remove `<div class="navbaritems" class="dropdown">`. Instead add class `navbaritems` to your dropdown element. So it will be `<li class="navbaritems dropdown">`. In addition to that wrap your search input into `<li class="navbaritems"><input...></li>`

Comment: Also some of your tags miss double quotes. You have `<li class=navbaritems>` but it should be `<li class="navbaritems">` and so on

Comment: @IvanBeliakov the quotes doesn't matter. It is just good practise but not actually required.

Comment: @tacoshy I think it will be harder to see error in HTML when the style is not consistent. Good point anyway

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback. I managed to fix the alignment issue, save for the search bar

Comment: I am looking to have the search bar go from being in the center, to have it go to the right of the navbar. I've checked all the CSS in relation to the Search Bar and whenever I set it to align to the right, the commands do not comply. I may repost to address that specific issue

Comment: @Sound_Flames If you applied my suggestion and wrapped your search input into `<li class="navbaritems">` then you can add to that particular `li` `float: right`